# IE loses focus on input field in modal

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, thickbox

I've got a fairly complex web app which I've condensed down to the following two HTML pages, and the problem still exists. The problem? The thickbox modal's (iframe) input field loses focus after a second (or less) in IE (8 & 9). It only occurs when it's in the modal. If you load the page on its own, focus is not lost.

I've tried both jQuery 1.4.2 and 1.7.2, and the issue occurs with each. I'd set this up as jsfiddle but don't think it supports being able to trigger a second page. Have set it up so you can see it [working here](http://home.comcast.net/~filehost/gen/test.html)

Base page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/thickbox-code/thickbox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
</head>
<body>
<a id="createAccountLink" class="thickbox" href="test2.html?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=400&width=600">Login</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/thickbox-code/thickbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Modal:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="ContactFormName" name="firstName" class="text" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#ContactFormName").focus();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I was building this from scratch, I wouldn't use thickbox. But changing it isn't really an option right now since it's heavily used elsewhere.

**Answer**
The focus has to be delayed. Even 1ms works.

```
setTimeout (function () {
$("#ContactFormName").focus();
}, 1);
```

Comment: Without any kind of demo there's no real way to debug this behavior.

Comment: I've added a link to a sample page. You can't edit it, but you can see it working. If I could get jsfiddle to fire an iframe, I'd set it up there.

Comment: Why are your scripts loaded in the body instead of the head? Also, while I haven't used thickbox, why does your modal include a full page's HTML? Don't you just need the form HTML? Finally, why would the modal need to load jQuery again?

Comment: It's faster to load scripts in the footer. The page itself is self contained. In its original form it's fairly complex PHP. In this instance, it's a modal that's being inserted as an iframe. That's one of the SOP's or thickbox. It needs to load jQuery again because it's its own page.

Comment: I've found that the setTimout is a useful 'fix' for a lot of issues like this. I've found it especially useful on Nokia browsers. I think it has to do with the order that some browsers render and execute the DOM. Sometimes a minuscule delay (I suspect it's less about the delay and more about just wrapping it in a separate function) is enough to get the rendering engine 'back on track'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The focus has to be delayed. Even 1ms works.

```
setTimeout (function () {
$("#ContactFormName").focus();
}, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET i've created an extension method:

```
public static void FocusDelayed(this WebControl control, Page page)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "focusDelayed", "setTimeout (function () { document.getElementById(\"" + control.ClientID + "\").focus(); }, 500);", true);
}
```

So, in the onload Page_Load of the popup I call it

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            controleName.FocusDelayed(Page);                
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Cheers